# Reading a voltage with isolation

Tags: adc, voltage-measurement, isolation, isolator

I need to measure a voltage on a power rail without connecting ground between power rail and my measuring ground reference. I want to create something like an isolated amplifier but with a much cheaper solution.

An idea I had is to put a big resistor to ground and measure voltage across it. Voltage range of power rail is between 30 and 160 V.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGp07q.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Are there trade-offs to do this?

Comment: Please draw a schematic of what you are proposing.

Comment: Added to question

Comment: If you need true isolation, a small microcontroller with ADC functionality on the measuring side which sends the digitized results trough a optocoupler to the MCU on the other side, is a cost-effective and accurate solution, I've found...

Comment: The circuit in that schematic won't work. R1 does nothing but waste power, and the opamp is used as a comparator with no feedback so it'll always output low (as low as the opamp can get to it's negative rail).

Comment: You need to show how the negative of PowerRail is referenced to GND. If not, you won’t measure anything. If close enough, there are instrumentation amplifiers with high common mode rage which can do it, but @Unimportant suggestion is best.

Comment: A differential amp can measure voltages without a direct reference to a common GND between the circuits.

Comment: Check out these answers to a similar question: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/545714/measuring-ac-voltage-from-floating-power-supply?rq=1